# Instance variable not retaining value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

This code is an ASP.net app that uses angularjs and typescript
In the html file, there is an ng-repeat (for populating a table) that is watching the variable this.csvData (which is an instance variable defined by `private csvData = []`) and the table generates perfectly. However, when I try console.log of that variable inside the updateDataDict function the console returns []. I'm not sure why....

```
public csvData = [];
private csvDataDict = {};

private getCSVdata() {
            var locationType = document.getElementById('dropdownButton').innerText.toLowerCase();
            console.log("Inside CSV data");

            let dataArray = [];

            this.$http.get(this.csvLocations[locationType]).then(function (res) {
                var result = res.data.toString().split(/\r\n|\n/);
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    let [sourceURL, redirectURL] = result[i].split(',');
                    dataArray.push({
                        sourceURL: sourceURL,
                        redirectURL: redirectURL
                    })
                }

            });

            this.csvData = dataArray;
            this.updateDataDict()
        }
 private updateDataDict() {
            console.log(this.csvData); // this line is screwing up.....

        }
```

Comment: this.updateDataDict() will be executed before the code inside then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this

```
 var result = res.data.toString().split(/\r\n|\n/);
 for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   let [sourceURL, redirectURL] = result[i].split(',');
     dataArray.push({
     sourceURL: sourceURL,
     redirectURL: redirectURL
   })
 }
```

is being executed after this

```
this.csvData = dataArray;
this.updateDataDict()
```

because its an asynchronous call, so you are checking the array before its actually being populated.

Comment: I'm not able to call this.updateDataDict() from within the callback because of the 'this' reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use fat arrow instead of a function.